# Using For Loop to Copy Matching Data

Tags: vba, excel

There are 2 separate tables - PT_Data and Suspects. Each table has Emp_Name as the first column and the second column is variable. I want to match Emp_Name from PT_Data to those in Suspects and update the corresponding value from Suspects table to column B in PT_Data table.

This is the code I have written.

```
          lastrowall = Sheets("Monthly Deals").Range("A1", Sheets("Monthly Deals").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Rows.Count
          lastrowsuspects = Sheets("Suspects").Range("A1", Sheets("Suspects").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Rows.Count


          For i = 1 To lastrowall
            For j = 1 To lastrowsuspects
                'MsgBox Sheets("PT_Data").Range("A" & i).Value
                    If Sheets("PT_Data").Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("Suspects").Range("A" & j).Value Then
                    Sheets("Suspects").Range("B" & j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("PT_Data").Range("B" & i).PasteSpecial
               End If
             Next j
           Next i
```

However, when a match is found, VB gives an "Application Defined or Object Defined Error". Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`Sheets("Suspects").Range("B" & j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("PT_Data").Range("B" & i).PasteSpecial`

To

```
 '~~> To paste values 
 Sheets("Suspects").Range("B" & j).Copy 
 Sheets("PT_Data").Range("B" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

or to Paste All use

```
Sheets("Suspects").Range("B" & j).Copy _
Destination:=Sheets("PT_Data").Range("B" & i)
```

BTW you can use formulas for this. VBA Not required. Use `Vlookup` as shown below. Put this formula in cell B1 of `PT_Data` and drag it down.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Suspects!A:B,2,0)
```

Comment: Woohoo! works like a charm! Thanks a ton, Siddharth!!